# How do I get find my iPhone off a iPhone I have bought second hand

Tags: iphone

Please help Me get find my iPhone off a second hand iPhone 5 need to get this off before I can use it for my son

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/how-to-clean-old-iphone-4-for-selling-after-buying-a-new-iphone-5

Comment: The fact that you the buyer of a second hand phone can't remove it without the seller is a good thing.  It might be a PITA for you right at the moment, but after you give that phone to your son he most likely won't get held-up for his phone because current security makes a stolen iPhone more of just a paperweight. =]

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this is by contacting the person you bought the iphone from. They need to delete the iphone from their icloud's "find my iphone"