# Erasing Apple products, how secure?

Tags: macos, ipad, mac, security, secure-erase

I am in the process of getting rid of some old Apple products:

1. Late 2009 iMac
2. iPad 2 (2012)
3. iPhone 4 (2011)

I've reset my iPad 2 using the feature in the preferences, to erase all content and settings.

I also plan to format my Mac by doing a clean install of High Sierra.

Would the above processes be secure enough for me to then sell / give my products away? or could data still be recovered?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/what-to-do-before-you-sell-give-away-or-trade-in-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touc https://support.apple.com/HT201065

Comment: Against whom do you seek security ?  A national intelligence agency ? (in which case burn the damn things).  The six-year old rather dim son (or daughter) of someone who picks up the items in a second-hand shop ?

Comment: The iMac is a different prospect. Unless you have always used FileVault, you will also need to secure erase the drive. See https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac/how-to-prepare-old-mac-sale-3483978/ for a decent guide. [Apple's own guides assume Filevault is always on]